# AWS Cloudwatch Scheduled Event how to access constant

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a lambda setup in AWS and have a schedule against the lambda to run.

I have a constant:`{ "foo" : "bar" }`

My Function Handler:

```
public void FunctionHandler(ScheduledEvent scheduledEvent, ILambdaContext context)
```

The question is, how do I access the value of "foo"?